# Using 'DateTime.LocalNow' with ISO 8601 Format

Tags: json, api, datetime, powerbi, powerquery

The API I am calling returns records by date. It takes two parameters startDate and stopDate in ISO 8601 format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ.

Example URI:

`https://feapif.callminer.net/api/v2/export/datesearch?startDate=2021-04-01T12%3A00%3A00.000Z&stopDate=2021-04-19T12%3A00%3A00.000Z`

I am trying to use 'DateTime.LocalNow'

''Date.ToText(Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()),-1),"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ")''

For the stopDate parameter so that when the query executes it is from 04/01 until whenever it is currently run. However when I run it as such I get an error:

"Message": "Could not parse dateString 'Date.ToText(Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()),-1),"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ)' into an instance of a DateTime object during Export Request Validation"
}

Is it possible to use this function with ISO format? Or am I doing something else wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            //endDate Variable to capture current date time in UTC
            endDate = DateTimeZone.LocalNow(),

            //date search GET Request
            Host = "https://feapif.callminer.net/api/v2/export/datesearch",

            //custom date search path with DateTimeZone.ToText for enddate and page parameter for pagination
           
            Path = "?startDate=2021-05-01T12%3A00%3A00.000Z&stopDate="&DateTimeZone.ToText((endDate)) & "&page="& Number.ToText(Page) &"&records=50&clientCaptureDate=true&scoreIds=58,55",
```

Comment: It would be great if you cold add a comment or an annotation explaining this code snippet for the future readers